# Fabric showWithCompletion after login

Tags: objective-c

I can login with  "[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion..."
I can showWithCompletion too.
But,I can't TWTRComposer showWithCompletion  after login completion.
not Crash, but Composer dialog not show.And show error

This is my Code

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession * _Nullable session, NSError * _Nullable error) {
//
TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];
NSString* composerText = @"Text";
[composer setText:composerText];

[composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[composer showFromViewController:self completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
    //
    if (result == TWTRComposerResultDone) {
        NSLog(@"Post Tweet successfully");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to post Tweet");
    }

   }];
}];
```

Error:

```
 CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "STHeitiTC-Medium" and got font with PostScript name "PingFangTC-Medium". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
```

Thx~

Comment: By the Way , in Xcode 7.0  iOS9.0

Comment: Are you calling this code from the main thread? Is it calling your callback on the main thread? Use `[NSThread isMainThread]` or break in the debugger to check.